# Observable subscribe not executing when data is returned

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscribe

I have this function in an angular 2 component.

```
 getSystem() {
 this.applicationService
 .getSystem(this.id)
 .subscribe(
   sysID => this.sysID = sysID,
   () => console.log("success"))
}
```

I am getting the sysId back successfully because i am then passing it on to another function, but success is never being printed. I need to be able to call another functionin place of printing success but that code is never being executed. Here is my service:

```
  getSystem(appId: String):Observable<string>{
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8090/app/cmticket/getsystem?app=' +appId)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
console.log("extract data")
return  res.json().stringList;
```

}
I am using the same code for another function and it works so not understanding why it is not executing even though data is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Your `subscribe()` has wrong signature [(docs)](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscriber.js~Subscriber.html). Use it like this:

```
.subscribe(
   sysID => this.sysID = sysID,
   null, // second positional argument is error
   () => console.log("success"))
```

or

```
.subscribe({
   next: sysID => this.sysID = sysID,
   complete: () => console.log("success")
})
```